# same content but different margin between front and back page

Tags: margins

i want display other margin of front, back page. (Front = odd page, back = even page)

2 sided pages are same content.

Ex i need :

- margin of front-odd page: landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm
- margin of back - even page: landscape,left=0.4cm,right=1.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm

**Minimal coding:**

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{product.tex}
%Type =1,2...10
No,Type,Name,Description
1,1,A1,D1
2,1,A1,D2
10,1,A4,D249
11,2,A10,D1000
12,2,A2,D11
18,3,A43,D318
19,3,A44,D319
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{products}{product.tex}

\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{%

  \DTLforeach*
    [\DTLiseq{\Type}{#1}]% Condition
    {products}% Database
    {\No=No,\Type=Type,\Name=Name,\Description=Description}{%
\noindent 
    \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
  ]
%Box A
  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  width=14cm, height= 10cm
  ]{xshift=3 cm,yshift=0cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
  \\
  \noindent \No
  }
  %Box B
  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  width=5cm, height= 5cm
  ]{xshift=10 cm,yshift=-1cm }{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}}


\end{tcbposter}
    \newpage
  }% 
}

\begin{document}

\printtype{1}

\printtype{2}

\end{document}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Your document *already* has alternating margins, because for `geometry`, the `left` option is an alias for `inner` and `right` for `outer`. You should really look at the LaTeX error messages, because they show severe problems in the layout: the poster is so big (high) that it can't fit on the first page along with the `\section*`, and since no break is allowed after a section title, they both go on the second page, leaving the first page empty: `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1...]`. Also, don't use `noindent` after ``\\``.

Comment: The poster is also too wide for your layout: `Overfull \hbox (2.84286pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 64--64`. And less importantly, `\par` isn't useful before `\section*`.

Comment: The reason why left margin seems irregular is that **after a section title, the first paragraph has no indentation by default**, but other paragraphs have. If you either do `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` (for instance, in the preamble) or put `\noindent` right before `\begin{tcbposter}`, then your left margin will show a regular alternance between odd and even pages.

Comment: @frougon, thank. i have updated my code: remove section and \par. How i can set margin for front page different with back page.

Comment: They are already different, did you try the `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`?

Comment: @frougon: thank for help. i want to set:margin of front: landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm
and 
margin of back: landscape,left=0.3cm,right=1.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm

Comment: Look, this is how I see the pages after a strong zoom out with `\parindent=0pt`: [image](https://imgur.com/Frzvqe0). Do you see the alternance? What is missing? (I don't know what front and back mean, but left means even-numbered and right means odd-numbered for pages, usually).

Comment: @frougon. where can i put "\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}" in my code? Thanks

Comment: For instance before `\begin{document}`. It could be right after too. But if you still want paragraph indentation elsewhere in the document, the alternative solution, as I said, is to put `\noindent` right before `\begin{tcbposter}`.

Comment: @frougon: thank you. i have added this \noindent as you said. But not solved my problem: front page:  left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm, even page: left=0.5cm,right=1.4cm. Hope you help afer some hours. Thanks

Comment: @KJO Thank for your comment. Front = odd page, back = even page. i will rethink about your idea.